# Film Location of Tommasino olive oil factory

Tags: film-location, the-godfather-2

Who knows where the olive oil mill/facility of Tommasino is (where Michael makes such a cute face when he tastes an olive)?

Comment: http://www.movie-locations.com/movies/g/godfather2.html ? http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0071562/locations ?